# OSX partition smaller than 16 GB

Tags: macos, partitioning, disk-utility

I'm trying to create a new partition because I need a case-sensitive filesystem for web development. But the Disk Utility won't allow me to create one smaller than 16.84 GB.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dragging the separator, try typing the required size manually. It should say: "*This partition is not drawn to scale. It's smaller than it appears here." However in your screenshot your size input seems disabled. Can you try adding a new partition and see if it enables the input as per my screenshot. What partition scheme are you using? GUID is assume?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Before you answered I created the partition, as you say the size box is disabled. Now I can't create another partition; the + is disabled. It also says I have only 16 MB free space, even though / has 63 GB free and "www" has 17 GB free. Please see the screenshots here http://imgur.com/a/MoPDt

Comment: Try formatting the www partition (backup if there's data on it) and try again. You're main partition should be fine. Have you partitioned your drive before (for Bootcamp or similar)?